# console is showing array but undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i am trying to console one state variable and i get this as output console

[image]

I am not able to understand what does this mean, it shows array of length two but when i click it, it is undefined

There are many console so underlined console output are from same line in different re render.
It is consoled every frame update using

this is my code

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    context.onRender = (renderState: RenderState, done) => {
      setRenderDone(() => done);
      setTopics(renderState.topics);
      setMessages(renderState.currentFrame);
      console.log("message is", renderState);
    };

    context.watch("topics");
    context.watch("currentFrame");

    context.subscribe(["mouse"]);
  }, [context]);
```

is this some behaviour of inspection tool or anything

Comment: It means that some code (which you haven't shown, and which might not even be your own) is modifying the `renderState` object after you logged it (but before you inspected it), and assigns `renderState.currentFrame = undefined`.

Comment: what does "which might not even be your own" means ?

Comment: That it might be the code of a library that you are using